# Passing a UILabel value of UItableviewcell to another view in iPhone returning null value?

Tags: xcode4, uitableview

I am a newbie to objective-C and got strucked at a particular point.I have to pass a UILabel value from tableviewcell to a label in Scrollview  when accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath action takes place .But the value is not passed ..I donno where Iam going wrong? I am writing this code :

```
    ViewController1.h:
UILabel *name1;
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UILabel *name1;

    ViewController1.m:
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

ViewController2 *v2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];
v2.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

[self presentModalViewController:v2 animated:YES];
 v2.provName=[name1 retain];   //name1 is the name of UILabel in TableView.
[v2 release];
}
    ViewController2.h
UILabel *providerName;
SString *provName;

    ViewController2.m:
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
providerName =[[UILabel alloc] init];
[providerName setFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,300,50) ];
providerName.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
providerName.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];

self.providerName.text=self.provName; 
 providerName.highlightedTextColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:providerName];
}
```

I can see  the label but not the value in it ...Y is it so?How to pass a UIlabel value to another view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath` just make some changes as below,

add

```
v2.provName=[name1 retain];   //name1 is the name of UILabel in TableView.
```

just above

```
[self presentModalViewController:v2 animated:YES];
```

and also as provName in V2 is synthesized no need to `retain` just assign it..

Edit: To get the Cell use the below

```
UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
v2.provName = cell.name1;
```

`UITableViewCell` can also your custom cell.

**Edit**: changes in `CellForRow`

Update your `cellForRow` as

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";

    UITableViewCell* cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault    reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
    }
    NSMutableDictionary *d = (NSMutableDictionary *) [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.accessoryType= UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;

    UILabel* name1= [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 320, 10)];
    name1.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
    [name1 setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
    [name1 setText:[d valueForKey:@"Name"]];
    name1.tag = 111;
    [cell addSubview:name1];
    [name1 release];

    return cell;
}
```

do not make your cell and name1 as global, use it only in `cellForRow`

update your `didSelectRow` as below

```
UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UILabel* name1 = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:111];
v2.provName = name1.text;
```

this should work fine.